# How is the workflow of tearDownClass from unittest.TestCase?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

How is the workflow of tearDownClass from `unittest.TestCase`? Is it called after each test method, or just in the end to "close the connection" of the test class?

Its explanation wasn't clarifying for me: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown

Answer (score 1):

It is called when you deallocate the class: in other words, when you finish with all of the test methods.  It's a direct cognate to the `setUpClass`  class method, but at the opposite end of execution.

Comment: Actually it's related to `setUpClass` method, not `setUp`. `setUp` is executed before every test from test cases class.

Comment: I tested printing the setUp setting and I repaired that the test database is recreated for each test method. I mean, tearDown seem to be called for each test method.

Comment: Correct: but `tearDownClass` will be called only upon exit from the test suite.